# Get the video time while playing android

Tags: android, video-streaming

I just want to ask how to get the time of the video while it plays. I am using videoview. Let us say for example, when you are playing a video with a length of 10 minutes and you are already in 4th minute, how can I get the value of 4 minute? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
Below is my code in playing video.

```
 private void PlayVideo(){
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(getActivity());
            mc.setAnchorView(videoMovie);           

            Uri video = Uri.parse(url);             
            videoMovie.setMediaController(mc);
            videoMovie.setVideoURI(video);
            videoMovie.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    videoMovie.start();
                }

            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_Video_Playback_on_Android_using_the_VideoView_and_MediaController_Classes)
and if you want to get the time of the video while it plays, this code is work well

```
 videoView.getDuration()
```